# Recovering the standard equation of an ellipse ( in an appropriate CS) from its "( added) distances from foci "definition.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, conic-sections

By the inelegant phrase " (added ) distances from foci definition" I simply mean this definition : an ellipse is the set of all points $P$ such that the sum of the distances from $P$ to two fixed points $F_1$ and $F_2$ is equal to a constant value $L$ ".

***My attempt stops at the end of a reasoning aiming at recovering the length $m$ of the minor axis, and apparently fails.***

Desmos construction : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qcmoz3iiqt

[image]

---

Let point $F_1 = (a,b) $ and $ F_2 = ( c,d)$.

With these points, one can define an ellipse , as the set of all points $(x,y)$ such that

$$ \sqrt{( x-a)²+(y-b)²} + \sqrt {(x-c)² + ( y-d)²} = L $$ .

The center $C= (M_1 , M_2)$ of this ellipse is the midpoint of segment $[F_1, F_2]$, and the distance of each focus from this center is $D/2$ ( half the distance from $F_1$ to $F_2$.

Knowing the angle   $A (= \arctan { (d-b)/(c-a)}$ )  that the line $(F_1, F_2)$ makes with the X-axis , one can define the coordinate system in which this ellipse has a standard equation:

- lime $X':  y-b = tan(A) ( x-a)$
- line $Y' : y-b = (-1/ \tan(A) ) ( x-a) $

My first goal is to recover the length of the minor axis , that is the length of segment $[CP]$,  point $P$ being the intersection of the ellipse with the new $Y$ axis , namely line $ Y'$.

[image]

$P$ must be at equal distance from both foci, hence, the length of segment $[PF_1]$ is $L/2$ . Also the length of $[CF_1]$ is $D/2$.

Let $\alpha$ be the angle $ \angle {PF_1C}$.

We have $ \alpha = \arccos { CF_1 / PF_1} = \arccos {(D/2)/(L/2) = \arccos {D/L}} $.

Hence finally the length $m$ of the minor axis should be  " hypothenuse times sine($\alpha$)" , namely  :

$ m = (L/2) \sin{(\alpha)}$.

But ***I can see the value I get with Desmos does not match the actual length of the minor axis on the graph.***

Comment: It's simpler to use Pythagora's theorem: $m=\sqrt{(L/2)^2-(D/2)^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always wondered this, and meant to work it out, so this question is a great opportunity. But I'm going to take a slightly different approach. Let me first rephrase things a little.

The *geometric* description of an ellipse is that it's the set of all points $P$ with the property that the sum of (i) the distance from $P$ to $F_1$ and (ii) the distance from $P$ to $F_2$  is some positive constant, which I'm going to call  $2d$ to make the algebra nicer later. I'll use the letter  G to refer to this description, as in "a G-ellipse".

The *coordinate* or *analytic* description is that it's the set of points $P = (x, y)$ satisfying an equation of the form $\frac{ (u-p)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(v - q)^2}{b^2} = 1$, where $u = x \cos t - y \sin t, v = x \sin t + y \cos t$ are coordinates in some rotated coordinate system, and (for nondegenerate ellipses), $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero; by negation, we can choose both to be positive.. In that rotated system, the ellipse-center is at $(u, v) = (p, q)$ and its major and minor axes have lengths $a$ and $b$ (possibly swapped depending on which of $a$ and $b$ is greater. I'll use C to refer to this description.

So the question becomes "Why do these two things define the same entity?", or perhaps, "Why is every G-ellipse also a C-ellipse, and vice-versa?"

You've taken the approach of (more or less) finding the equation of the C-ellipse from the G-ellipse description. I'm going to insert a couple of steps to make things easier.

1. Observe that if we rotate everything by some amount, a G-ellipse is still a G-ellipse (because distance is invariant under rotation). If we do the same thing, replacing $x$ and $y$ with
   \begin{align}
   x' &= x \cos w - y \sin w \\
   y' &= x \sin w + y \cos w
   \end{align}
   then, after some simplification, we still have a C-ellipse, but with the rotation amount $u$ replaced by $u \pm w$ (I can't bring myself to work out which one!).

This means that if we can prove that every G-ellipse with horizontally-aligned foci is a C-ellipse, then we will also know this is true for *any* G-ellipse. I'll actually show this claim, and show that the C-ellipse has the simple form where $t = 0$. I'll call this an *axis-aligned* C-ellipse, which has the coordinate form $\frac{(x-p)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-q)^2}{b^2} = 1$.

2. Observe that if we translate everything by some amount (move left, right, up, down, or a combination of these), a G-ellipse remains a G-ellipse (because distance is invariant under translation). Similarly, if we translate an axis-aligned C-ellipse, it remains an axis-aligned C-ellipse, because replacing $x$ with $x - r$ and $y$ with $y - s$ changes
   $$
   \frac{(x-p)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-q)^2}{b^2} = 1
   $$
   into
   \begin{align}
   \frac{((x-r)-p)^2}{a^2} + \frac{((y-s)-q)^2}{b^2} = 1
   \frac{(x-(p+r))^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-(q+s))^2}{b^2} = 1
   \end{align}
   which still has the form of an axis-aligned C-ellipse.

With these two "transformation rules" in hand, we can consider your question for the simple case where $F_1$ and $F_2$ lie on a horizontal line (using observation 1), and where their midpoint is the origin (observation 2).

So at this point, we have
\begin{align}
F_1 = (f, 0) \\
F_2 = (-f, 0)
\end{align}
Points with summed distances $2d$ from these are points $(x, y)$ satisfying
$$
\sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x + f)^2 + y^2} = 2d
$$
Note here that we must have $d > f$, because for any point other than the origin, the distances to $(f, 0)$ and $(-f, 0)$ sum to more than $2f$.

In particular, when $x= 0$, this gives
\begin{align}
\sqrt{f^2 + y^2} &+ \sqrt{f^2 + y^2} = 2d\\
2\sqrt{f^2 + y^2} & = 2d\\
f^2 + y^2 & = d^2\\
 y^2 & = (d^2 - f^2)\\
 y & = \pm \sqrt{d^2 - f^2}\\
\end{align}

In the generic axis-aligned C-ellipse centered at the origin, whose equation is
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{ b^2} = 1
$$
when $x = 0$, we get $y = b$. So (as a kind of foreshadowing), if our G-ellipse is to be a C-ellipse, we'll need to have
$$
b = \sqrt{d^2 - f^2}.
$$
(I've chosen the positive root in order to ensure that $b$ is positive.)

Doing a similar thing for the case where $y = 0$, we get
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(x-f)^2} &+ \sqrt{(x+f)^2} = d \\
(x-f) &+ (x+f) = 2d \\
2x&= 2d \\
x = d
\end{align}

which similarly leads us to the requirement that
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} = 1 \\
\frac{d^2}{a^2} = 1\\
a = d
\end{align}

This means that *if* our G-ellipse, defined by
$$
\sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x + f)^2 + y^2} = d
$$
is actually a C-ellipse, then that C-ellipse must have the equation
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2 }{d^2}+ \frac{ y^2}{d^2 - f^2} &= 1 \\
\end{align}
defined for $-d \le x \le d$.

We can do a little algebra here to express $y$ in terms of $x$:
\begin{align}
\frac{ y^2}{d^2 - f^2} &= 1 - \left( \frac{x^2 }{d^2} \right) \\
y^2 &= (d^2 - f^2)\left(1 - \left( \frac{x^2 }{d^2}\right) \right) \tag{*}\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{(d^2 - f^2)\left(1 - \left( \frac{x^2 }{d^2}\right)\right)} \\
\end{align}

Now let's see whether points of the form described by this formula (or by formula (*), which will be the one we use in practice) in fact satisfy the equation of the G-ellipse. We'll substitute ( * ) into the left side of
$$
\sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x + f)^2 + y^2} = 2d
$$
and see whether it reduces to $2d$. Buckle up!

Let's start with the first term, $\sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2}$:
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2}  \\
&= \sqrt{(x-f)^2 + (d^2 - f^2)\left(1 - \left( \frac{x^2 }{d^2}\right) \right)}  & \text{, after substituting in (*)}  \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 - 2fx + f^2 + (d^2 - f^2) - \left( (d^2 - f^2)\frac{x^2 }{d^2}\right) }  \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 - 2fx  + d^2  - d^2 \frac{x^2 }{d^2} + f^2\frac{x^2 }{d^2}  }  \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 - 2fx  + d^2  - x^2 + \frac{(fx)^2 }{d^2}  }  \\
&= \sqrt{- 2fx  + d^2  + \left(\frac{fx}{d}\right)^2}  \\
&= \sqrt{d^2 - 2d\frac{fx}{d}  + \left(\frac{fx}{d}\right)^2}  \\
&= \sqrt{(d- \frac{fx}{d})^2} \\
&= d- \frac{fx}{d}
\end{align}
where that last simplification needs some explanation -- how did I know which square root to take? You'll see above that $x$ lies in the range $-d$ to $d$, so the fraction term in the square root is between $-f$ and $f$. Because $d > f$, we know that $(d- \frac{fx}{d})$ is positive. So the choice of square root is justified.

Similarly, the second term becomes
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{(x+f)^2 + y^2}  \\
&= \sqrt{(x+f)^2 + (d^2 - f^2)\left(1 - \left( \frac{x^2 }{d^2}\right) \right)}  & \text{, after substituting in (*)}  \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 + 2fx + f^2 + (d^2 - f^2) - \left( (d^2 - f^2)\frac{x^2 }{d^2}\right) }  \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 + 2fx  + d^2  - d^2 \frac{x^2 }{d^2} + f^2\frac{x^2 }{d^2}  }  \\
&= \sqrt{x^2 + 2fx  + d^2  - x^2 + \frac{(fx)^2 }{d^2}  }  \\
&= \sqrt{ 2fx  + d^2  + \left(\frac{fx}{d}\right)^2}  \\
&= \sqrt{d^2 + 2d\frac{fx}{d}  + \left(\frac{fx}{d}\right)^2}  \\
&= \sqrt{(d + \frac{fx}{d})^2} \\
&= d + \frac{fx}{d}
\end{align}
Summing these two, we get $2d$, as required.

So our G-ellipse is in fact exactly the same as our axis-aligned C-ellipse. And the minor radius of our C-ellipse (the $y$-value when $x = 0$) is $\sqrt{d^2 - f^2}$, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and reader-friendly answer !